# Using a 2nd thread to shutdown the main app at a certain time in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, shutdown

I have been searching for solutions for this for a while now, and some examples solve one part and others solve another, so hence my question, so hopefully someone can point me in the direction I need,

I am developing a Python app that basically is a constant loop, using a USB scanner to read QR codes to log attendance for a community center that I volunteer for.

in pseudo-code:

```
def shutdownThread()
   create a thread that shuts down this app (and PC) at or after a certain time
    
    ...
    

def mainLoop()
     while true:
         do the scanning & logging function
```

I've considered using schedule or threading, but I am confused about how the use of sleep(x) will lag or block the main thread execution. The app will run on a Lenovo m73 SFF i3 PC, Win10 and is slightly laggy as it is. I have read up on the GIL structure of single threading so hence I am after some advice and perhaps some code snippets that I can experiment with,

Cheers in advance,

Comment: maybe you should use global variable `running = True` and `while running:` and later set `running = False` to stop `while`-loop.

Comment: maybe you should use one theard and inside `while`-loop check `time` and use `break` to exit loop. Before loop get `start = time.time()` and inside loop check `if time.time() - start > some_value: break` or do it directly in `while time.time() - start <= some_value:`